# SailsJS: not able to connect to postgresql database

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, postgresql-13

We have SailsJS app with postgresql adapter. Requests made to server chokes at database query via models. i.e `Users.find()`. Database server is up and running, connection string is correct and one can connect to database using same connection string.

datastore has default adaptor set to `sails-postgresql`. If database adaptor is changed to mysql or default sails-disk, it works. But `sails-postgresql` is not

Comment: What version of the adapter are you using? Also, what's the version of Sails?

Comment: Sails.JS v1.2.5 and `sails-postgresql` is adapter being used